# Solr: Additive boost query without resorting to DisMax - is it possible?

Tags: solr, lucene, dismax

I have a disjunctive Lucene query like this:
`(clause_1 OR clause_2 OR ... OR clause_N)` and I want to add an additive boost query on top of it, just like the `bq` parameter in `DisMax` parser.

I tried `{!edismax qf='' bq='my_boost_query'}(clause_1 OR clause_2 OR ... OR clause_N)` but it returned zero result. (I assume it might be caused by the empty `qf` parameter)

Is is possible to do it without rewriting my query using `DisMax` format? Perhaps some special syntax of `Lucene` query parser, like `_val_` and such? Or may be `DisMax` wrapper does the job, but I am just missing something in the above query syntax?